# How to verify a Microsoft certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate

This is the certificate https://gist.github.com/larytet/2fb447e875831577584592cd99980fd1  (x5t VjWIUjS5JS3eAFdm2dnydlZfY-I)

I am doing

```
openssl verify -verbose -x509_strict certificate.pen
```

I am getting

```
CN = estsclient.coreauth.outlook.com
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error certificate.pem: verification failed
```

Where do I find the certificate, the whole chain or the root which should be installed in my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the CA certificate, and most real CAs will list locations where its certificate can be found in an extension in each certificate they issue.

With OpenSSL, you can view this extension:

```sh
openssl x509 -text -noout < certificate.pem
```

Look for the "Authority Information Access extension", and its "CA Issuers" field to find the URL and download the certificate from [Microsoft.](http://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/Microsoft%20IT%20TLS%20CA%202.crt)

Because this file is encoded with DER, it needs to be transcoded to PEM for use with `openssl verify`:

```sh
openssl x509 -inform der < Microsoft\ IT\ TLS\ CA\ 2.crt > Microsoft\ IT\ TLS\ CA\ 2.pem
```

Because you just downloaded this file from who knows where over HTTP, you need some way to verify *its* authenticity.

You'll notice that it too lists an issuer, so you can perform this process recursively to obtain the entire certificate chain back to a root certificate that you already trust. Usually, we trust the certificates that come pre-installed on our systems. But, in theory, an attacker could have compromised that set, so people sometimes do find out-of-band means to verify their root CA certificates. What's appropriate for you depends on your application.

The chain of certificates that you download on your way to the trust anchor are "intermediate" certificates; you don't have to trust them directly, because you'll be verifying a chain starting with one of the anchors on your system.

Concatenate the PEM-encoded certificates, including headers and footers, together in a single file of untrusted certificates. In my case, the "Baltimore CyberTrust Root" certificate that issued the "Microsoft IT TLS CA 2" intermediate certificate is pre-installed as a root CA on my system, so I only have to download the Microsoft certificate, and it's the only one in my file of "untrusted" certificates.

Now you have the necessary information to attempt your original command:

```sh
openssl verify --verbose -untrusted Microsoft\ IT\ TLS\ CA\ 2.pem  -x509_strict certificate.pem
```

Comment: Is there by a chance a command line utility which follows the chain? My ultimate goal is to verify the certificate in the context of a Docker build.

Comment: @Larytet I don't believe so. Looking for ready-made tools or libraries is off-topic for this site. If you need help scripting the tools you have, you can post a question about that. This can also be pretty easy to write your own tool for, depending on your platform.

Comment: In my innocent lack of awareness I thought that all I need is to install a missing root certificate like DigiCert. Just a reasonably good probability that the certificate is valid would be good enough in my case.

Comment: @Larytet Maybe you can rewind a bit and explain why you want to validate a certificate like this in a shell. These certificates are most useful in a protocol like TLS, and there, proper configuration ensures that intermediate certs are transmitted. In that case, installing a missing root would be all you need.

Comment: I verify JWT tokens signed by the key from https://gist.github.com/larytet/2fb447e875831577584592cd99980fd1   I find the idea of loading the certificate in the run-time disturbing. I would prefer to load the public key only once when I create the container and let the container run unchanged until the next deployment or the expiration date. Naturally I want to make a reasonable effort of validation of the key I have just downloaded from HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this question I ended up with something like this + lot of comment

```
RUN curl --silent https://outlook.com/autodiscover/metadata/json/1 > ./outlook.com.autodiscover.metadata.json.1
RUN pem_file=certificate.pem \
    && echo "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" > $pem_file \
    && cat ./outlook.com.autodiscover.metadata.json.1 | jq --raw-output '.keys[0].keyvalue.value' >> $pem_file \
    && echo "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" >> $pem_file \
    && cat $pem_file \
    && openssl x509 -text -noout  < $pem_file | grep "CA Issuers" \
    && curl https://cacerts.digicert.com/BaltimoreCyberTrustRoot.crt.pem > rootCA.pem  \
    && curl http://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/Microsoft%20IT%20TLS%20CA%202.crt | openssl x509 -inform der >> rootCA.pem \
    && curl https://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertCloudServicesCA-1.crt | openssl x509 -inform der >> rootCA.pem \
    && cat rootCA.pem \
    && cat certificate.pem

RUN pem_file=certificate.pem && openssl verify -verbose -x509_strict -untrusted rootCA.pem $pem_file
```